# IE8 with jQuery width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a width dynamically on a div.  This is correctly working with Safari, Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8.  This is using jQuery UI for the slider function.  Here is my code so far:

```
var ourStoryPosts = $(".ourStory .grid_12mod").children();
var ourStoryLength = ourStoryPosts.length;
var ourStoryWidth = $(ourStoryPosts[2]).outerWidth(true);
var ourStoryWrapperWidth = ourStoryLength * ourStoryWidth;
var maxSlider = ourStoryWrapperWidth - 1020;

$(".ourStory .grid_12mod").width(ourStoryWrapperWidth);

$(".ourStorySlider").slider({ 
    step: 1, 
    max: maxSlider,
    slide: function( event, ui) {
        $(".ourStory").css({
            "left" : -ui.value
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am using variables to set these values.  The `width()` method is not working as expected.

I have tried using the `String()` constructor to explicitly cast to a string.  I have tried using `+ "px"` at the end of the expression as well.  Each time, the div is being set to `0px`.  Why is this not working correctly?

Comment: try using parseFloat on the variables and console log each line to see what is going wrong

Comment: @CR41G14 No luck with `parseFloat`.

Comment: OK suggested using the css property instead of Width? they should both have the same outcome unless other css parent rules prohibit

Comment: When you do a console.log of the variable ourStoryWrapperWidth what comes up?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Right, I should've been clear.  Hardcoding the values works fine.  It logs `1275` which is correct for my needs.  So, the value is right.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the css property width?

```
$(".ourStory .grid_12mod").css('width', ourStoryWrapperWidth.toString() + 'px');
```

Comment: Is there some other css on the parent or max-width property overruling which IE8 takes as priority?

Comment: As I said up top in a comment, hardcoding the values works fine.  Putting in the number `1275` makes it work correctly.

Comment: Does this suggested code put the inline css "width" on the element when you inspect it using IE8 developer tools F12?

Comment: Yes it does.  The width attribute is inline.

Comment: Yet the div is not resized?

Comment: The div is resized when I put in the number of `1275` it shows the `width` attribute inline width `1275px`.  When setting the `width()` method with a variable, it shows `0px`

Comment: If you alert ourStoryWrapperWidth.toString() + 'px' do you get 0px in Ie8?

Comment: Yes, for some reason I do.  Perhaps it's to do with the variables I am grabbing before that.

Comment: remove all console logs and put the html and css and code up on jsfiddle, also check for errors in bottom left corener

Comment: I think I found the problem.  `ourStoryLength` logs `5` in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.  In IE8 it logs 1.  Using `.size()` yields the same results.

Comment: Fixed the issue.  I posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the actual issue was, but using native JS fixed it for me:

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".grid_12mod");
var ourStoryChildren = elem.children;
```

Using the jQuery 1.9 method of `children()` logged a result of `5` elements in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, while IE8 logged `1`.  Using the native `children` attribute of the `elem` object fixed the problem and logged `5` for all browsers.

The reason this was logging `0` is because IE8 was returning only `1` child element, when `5` existed, therefore the math was off and IE8 was trying to find the second array element when it only found `1` element.